# Sigma algebras and intervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let's say we got three intervals, in which $b>a$,
we got that $(a,b) \subset [a,b)\subset[a,b]$; is it then also true that if let's say $(a,b) \in S_{1}$, $S_{1}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, that another $\sigma$-algebra which contains $[a,b)$, let's call it $S_{2}$, also contains $S_{1}$, i.e. $S_{1} \subset S_{2}$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are phrasing the question,  the answer is no. For instance, let 
$$
S_1=\{\emptyset,  (0,1)\},\ \ \ S_2=\{\emptyset, [0,1)\}.
$$

Comment: How about if $S_{1}$ = ${empty, (a,b)}$

Comment: Yes, of course.  When I started writing I was thinking of a different example, that's why I wrote the more convoluted one.

Comment: It is then also correct to say that $(a,b) \in S_{2}$?

Comment: No. In the example above,  $(0,1)\not\in S_2$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now.